# Liquid error: Exceeded maximum number of unique handles for collections. (Shopify)

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

What would cause this error to appear on a Shopify site that has had no theme or app changes for a long time?

> Liquid error: Exceeded maximum number of unique handles for collections.

Comment: Do you have `collections[handle]` in a for loop somewhere? Haven't experienced this but it seems like the `all_products[handle]` limit of 20 calls, so there seems to be a limit for collections as well.

Comment: I have something like that, yes.

Comment: [This](https://freakdesign.com.au/blogs/news/exceeded-maximum-number-of-unique-handles-for-all_products) article should shed some light on your issue. My guess is Shopify didn't enforce the limit before or your store fill through the cracks.

Answer (score 2):

I have too many collections.

The `collections` array seems to only allow looping through the first 1,000 items, or fetching 1,000 items using syntax like `{% assign filter_collection = collections[handle] %}`. (thanks @drip)

The error message is output on the 1,000th time that I call `{% assign filter_collection = collections[handle] %}`.

I could not find a reference to this in the official documentation, but the limit of 1000 iterations can be demonstrated like so:

```
    shop.collections_count: {{ shop.collections_count }}
    collections.length:     {{ collections.length }}
    collections | size:     {{ collections | size }}
    
    {%- assign i = 0 -%}
    {%- for col in collections -%}
        {%- assign i = i | plus:1 -%}
        {%- if i > 995 -%}
            {{ i }}
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
```

Outputs:

```
shop.collections_count: 1814
collections.length:     1814
collections | size:     1814
996
997
998
999
1000
```